# Send text to email via JS or any widget service

Tags: javascript, email, service, jekyll, octopress

Problem: I have a jekyll based site (static site at GitHub pages) and I need to add widget with textbox, where visitor can write his question and send it to me. I see 2 variants: send email (or something else) via JS (don't know, how to do this) or use any service that provides simple textarea with sending button

Solution: not found.

Please, give me some ideas about solution for this problem, may be you know any free service that provides required functionality?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - Please review your question

Comment: @QuintinBalsdon, please, check my answer (found a way myself). And I don't ask to recomend anything, I asked for a way to solve this problem and if here is no another way, recomend something. Sorry for my English, I know it's very bad :(

Comment: It's not your english I was commenting on, your english is fine. The question is fairly broad and therefore it would be difficult for anyone other than yourself to provide a satisfactory answer. I am glad you have found the tool that suites your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use form service like https://formspree.io/.
Really easy to use.

Comment: thank you very much! It's the best solution for my problem!

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer myself:

1. Use GitReports (open source and free) for site repo (username/username.github.io)
2. Create form for site and use GitReports as gateway for creating anonymous issue

I hope, this will help not only for me.